# How to compile a .o file to a Linux kernel module (.ko) file?

Tags: c, linux, module, makefile, kernel

1. I write some code. Such as a `test.c`. I plan to compile it to a `test.o` file, and supply a head file.
2. Then, I supply this .o file to another programmer, he is writing a Linux kernel module, e.g a `driver.ko`.

My question is: can he include my .o file in his .ko? How to write the make file? Is there any special requirement when I compile my .o file?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you All, I find out the solution.
obj-m += helloworld.o 
helloworld-objs := hello.o world.o

all:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) hello.o
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) helloworld.ko

clean:
 make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean